# Custom app which need microphone access not working on Microsoft Teams Moble apps ( IOS and Android ) but working in all browsers (phones & desktops)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, botframework, microsoft-teams

Working on a custom application (personal tab app) which requires access to microphone.  Tried using WEBRT sdk and Azure text to speech servies but same results ( everything works well on all browser (phone and desktop) but not in Teams Mobile app ( tested on both IOS and android ).  Any pointers for help ?

Comment: Please go through [Device capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/device-capabilities-overview) to integrate device capabilities, such as camera, QR or barcode scanner, photo gallery, microphone, and location with web apps.

Answer (score 0):

Moving comment to answer for visibility :

Please go through [Device capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/device-capabilities-overview) to integrate device capabilities, such as camera, QR or barcode scanner, photo gallery, microphone, and location with web apps.